# Synonym filter with "&" not working in elasticsearch suggest with standard tokenizer

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize, autosuggest

My goal is that if I have something like `"s & p indices"` indexed, that I can also suggest this if the user searches `s and p`, `s & p`, or `s p`. However, there seems to be something peculiar about the & as the below synonym set-up does not work for it. I have the below mapping for my `suggest index`.

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "suggest_analyzer": {
          "type":      "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter":    [ "lowercase", "my_synonym_filter" ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "my_synonym_filter": {
          "type": "synonym", 
          "synonyms": [ "&, and", "foo, bar" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I have the below mapping for my `type`

```
{
  "properties" : {
    "name" : { "type" : "string" },
    "name_suggest" : {
      "type" : "completion",
      "index_analyzer" :  "suggest_analyzer",
      "search_analyzer" : "suggest_analyzer"
    }
  } 
}
```

If I index the following object:

```
{
  "name" : "s & p indices",
  "name_suggest" : { 
    "input" : [ "s & p indices"] 
  }
}
```

Searching for `s and` does not return the indexed suggestion. However, the synonym for foo and bar work as expected.

I assume it probably is related to how the standard tokenizer tokenizes on &, but I do not know how to work around the issue. Is there a way to get the tokenizer to exclude splitting on the & and/or treating it differently?

Comment: What do you index when you index the `s & p` document?

Comment: @IanGabes I added the object that I am indexing to the OP. It's very simple for the sake of this problem

Answer (score 2):

Your current issue apparently lies in the choice of tokenizer for `suggest_analyzer`. The standard tokenizer does not generate a token for `&`, and thus the token stream passed to your filters do not see the `&` token for them to be able to replace it. You can see how this works using the [_analyze endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/analysis-intro.html?q=analy#analyze-api)

In this case, the tokens generated by the standard tokenizer look like this for the text `s & p`

```
"tokens": [
      {
         "token": "s",
         "start_offset": 5,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "p",
         "start_offset": 9,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 2
      }
   ]
```

The standard tokenizer eats the &. The simplest way to get everything to work here is to change your analyzer to use the whitespace analyzer, which will not  strip out special characters or do much work at all, its job is to split on white space.

I modified your mapping to be this:

```
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "suggest_analyzer": {
          "type":      "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter":    [ "lowercase", "my_synonym_filter" ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "my_synonym_filter": {
          "type": "synonym", 
          "synonyms": [
              "&, and",
              "foo, bar" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

That will get you results like this:

```
{
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "name_suggest": [
      {
         "text": "s and",
         "offset": 0,
         "length": 5,
         "options": [
            {
               "text": "s & p",
               "score": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to replace ampersands before hitting the tokenizer, using a char filter. Like so:

```
            ...
            "char_filter" : {
                "replace_ampersands" : {
                    "type" : "mapping",
                    "mappings" : ["&=>and"]
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "autocomplete": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "char_filter" : ["replace_ampersands"],
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "addy_synonym_filter",
                        "autocomplete_filter",
                    ]
                }
            }
            ...
```